# Error thrown while imputing values using regression FNN package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to impute missing values using regression and have searched thoroughly online and it hasn't been of much help. I read the FNN package documentation for the knn.reg function and find it difficult to interpret. I have a column of missing values in the test data which i want to predict using my training data and have a code like this ::

```
regress<-knn.reg(data.train[data.train[,4]==1,][c(1,2,3)],test=data.test[c(1,2,3)],data.test[c(2)],5)
```

But I get the following error:: Error in get.knnx(train, test, k, algorithm) : Data include NAs. The column which contains missing values is col #2.  When I exclude the column which has NA values i.e.

```
regress<-knn.reg(data.train[data.train[,4]==1,][c(1,2,3)],test=data.test[c(1,3)],data.test[c(2)],5)
```

I get an error:: Error in get.knnx(train, test, k, algorithm) : Number of columns must be same!. Please help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider the `mice` package (and read part of the [paper](http://doc.utwente.nl/78938/1/Buuren11mice.pdf)).

Using standard settings which have been proven to a good starting point:

```
library(mice)
mi <- mice(dataset)
mi.reg <- with(data=mi,exp=glm(y~x+z))
```

Here, simply calling `mice()` on your data will fill in each `NA` value. Finer tuning is of course possible (and needed if it would take too long to converge, or if you have reason to believe it is not accurate). Many different types of imputations are possible and are listed on page 16.